# Dotnet - cannot install any global tools

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, dotnet-cli

I am trying to run command:

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-try --version 1.0.20474.1
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-try
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-try --version 1.0.20474.1
dotnet tool install -g --add-source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json" Microsoft.dotnet-try
```

But always getting the same issue

> Cannot use file stream for
> [C:\Users\pawel.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.deps.json]:
> No such file or directory A fatal error was encountered. The library
> 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in
> 'C:\Users\pawel.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'.
> Failed to run as a self-contained app.
>
> - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\Users\pawel.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.runtimeconfig.json'
>   was not found.
> - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\Users\pawel.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.runtimeconfig.json'
>   file and specify the appropriate framework. C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Problem
>   starting the plugin
>   'C:\Users\pawel.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe'.
>   The operation was canceled.
>   [C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Temp\mb243djx.nyn\restore.csproj] The
>   tool package could not be restored. Tool 'microsoft.dotnet-try' failed
>   to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.
>
> For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit
> https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool

I checked and indeed those files does not exists

> C:\Users\pawel.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.deps.json
> hostpolicy.dll

Dotnet info

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.101
 Commit:    d05174dc5a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.1
  Commit:  b02e13abab

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.600 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Curious if you ever figured this out? I'm seeing this too.

Comment: I have been able to install without the the `-g` or `--global` switches. However, it forces me to run out of certain directories despite being globally on my %PATH%. So, I too am curious about a solution.